For a given mileage, which is more profitable, multiple short flights or fewer long flights?
In a simplified scenario, which is more profitable for an airline, operating 10 short flights (400 miles) or 5 long flights (800 miles), for a total of 4,000 miles flown in each case?
To make things simple lets consider both cases will have:

same aircraft
same weather
same payload
same landing fees
same fuel price
same number of passengers
only one class type of tickets
no extra revenue generated during flight
Assume that the long flight is twice the price of the short flight.


You do a lot of assumptions, but you miss the economic scale. If it is not profitable, airlines either do not flight or they increase ticket price. Why to invest on a less profitable route? (Then management, cost reductions, optimisation differentiate airlines, but that is outside your question).

You didn't mention ticket prices.  Because this is the only variable that affects revenue, which after operating costs are subtracted, affects profitability.  And it is the variable mist easily controlled by the airline.  Without including it the question is unanswerable.

Rather than the short/long haul comparison, look at "stage length": How to understand "Stage length, for payload calculations includes 85% wind"?. The stage length influences profitability.

@MichaelHall I left price out intentionally because I thought that would be part of the answer I'm looking for(like how would the airline setup tickets pricing). If you ask me, I would say the long flight would be twice the price of the short flight since is twice the distance???

Asking how airline pricing strategy works is like asking how to design an airplane.

@MichaelHall I have decided to update the question stating long flight is twice the price of the short flight.

Keep in mind that operating short flights (or partnering with an airline who does so) is part of how airlines profitably operate long flights with a hub-and-spoke route network. More people will fly the long-haul flight between Los Angeles and Tokyo if people who live in Las Vegas, Phoenix, etc... can access it through connections provided by short-haul flights between these cities and Los Angeles. The airline is concerned with profitability of their network as a whole beyond just the profitability of each flight.

@ZachLipton yes I'm aware of that, like American-Envoy partnership for example.

OP edited the question and added information. I think the question was closed in haste, not considering the edits OP made.

The latest edit dropped ticket price out of the equation.

@Jpe61 thanks for updating the title and description, it made it more clear of what my question is/was.

The only case when it may make sense (but one would have to run the numbers) is for very long flights, e.g. Europe-Australia, and comparing non-stop vs. a single stop near the mid-point, where, on a direct flight, the amount of fuel to be carried during the first half of the flight for the second half could have an impact on the total cost. On shorter hops as in your example, the difference in fuel is small compared to the overall (you’ll probably need more reserve fuel than actual fuel for the flight).

Also, as you ask which is more profitable, but then impose many conditions which mean the revenue doesn’t change, your actual question here is if the cost changes. Profitability is quite likely to depend a lot on revenue changes: whether the airline would have more or less passengers on the various segments, whether they would be able to charge more (or less) for the same itinerary (because it becomes shorter/more convenient or the opposite), etc. There are then considerations specific to the route and airports and the potential market for each.

Assuming the ticket for the twice as long flight would cost twice as much, it would be more profitable to fly longer flights.
For the same amount of flight distance, 4000 miles in this case, flying shorter trips takes more time due to turn around times, and less time travelling at cruising speed, so you earn less in the same amount of time.
Shorter flights would consume more fuel due to having twice the amount of taxiing and takeoffs (descents will not compensate for takeoff, not even close).
Shorter flights would have twice the landing fees and hightened maintenance cost for the aircraft since number of operations is a deciding factor in some maintenance cycles.
Crew cost would most likely end up being higher since the actual time used for flying will be less in short flight scenario, and many salary models have built in operation compensation.
Shorter flights also require double the support functions (such as dispatch/flight planning etc.)

Those were very good points. Didn't thought about the landing fees were going to be double, duh now thinking about it is obvious, lol. Thanks

In aviation, as in many industries, "longer production runs" are way more efficient and profitable than short stints. Less hassle, more producing.

@Jpe61, more fuel efficient, absolutely.  But profitability depends heavily on pricing strategy and load factors.

@MichaelHall yeah that depends a lot on the pricing, but I just wanted to focus this question in the distance alone in a simple 1 to 1 comparison. Jpe61 brought up the points that answered my question, which now that I see them most were obvious, but as they say sometimes you need someone else to show you what you can't see.

@Jpe61 any idea about how much more profitable would the long flight be? (just a rough estimate). Like 10%, 20%, 30% more?

@MichaelHall I think you missed the OP updated the question to include the pricing strategy: the long flight is twice as expensive as the short one. I tried to address the load factors by giving a crude estimate of the efficiency of time usage, I may reword a little to better describe that: over time, shorter trips will yield less miles, and for that reason (in addition other factors) to  also less profit.

@gabe as I guess you know, your question is pretty much academic. The variables in this game are such that real world pricing simply does not work that way. Raw operating costs have surprisingly little to do with actual ticket prices, but I would guess, and I can't stress enough that this is just a guess with some knowledge behind it, the longer flight has 10 to 20 precent lower opertating cost per mile than the shorter one in the scenario you presented.
